# Dynamic Array in a loop in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to create a code which'll store new arrays based on user demand and perform particular set of operations on it.  So, considering I don't really need to store that array once the operation is being done on it, I thought of overwriting that same array, but that's where I'm having problems.

```
int main() 
{
    int i, T;

    scanf("%d", &T);
    int res[T];//for T cases I'll have T outputs so saving it in an array

    for(i=0; i<T; i++)
    {
        int size, j;
        scanf("%d", &size);
        int ary[size];
        for(j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d ", &ary[j]);
        }
        //In each case I'm just declaring an array and getting a result n storing in another array
        res[i]=fn(ary, size);//fn returns 1 if array forms Circular Prime else 0
    }

    for(i=0; i<T; i++)
    {
        if(res[i]==1)
            printf("YES\n");
        else
            printf("NO\n");            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?  What's the problem, and what's the expected result?  Please try to make your question easy to answer!

Comment: What's your question? It's unclear to me what the problem is. Please describe what you expect it to do and what it does instead.

Comment: Where is dynamic allocation you tagged ? And what is problem that you face ?

Comment: @ameyCU I assume that's what he's trying to do with `int res[T]` and `int ary[size]`.

Comment: @WillVousden  whole question is unclear . Yeah sorry stupid question .

Comment: @ameyCU Because `T` and `size` are not constants.

Comment: I need this code to input a number X and ask the user X number of times for an array size and input that array call the function fn where it checks for whether or not that array forms a circular prime if yes then I'm saving it  as 1 in res[] else 0 then in the end printing it.

Comment: Change `scanf("%d ", &ary[j]);` to `scanf("%d", &ary[j]);`

Comment: You have an answer with 3 up votes so far, and haven't even stated a question, yet.  Now that is great service!

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with this code. The problem lies in either the `fn` subroutine, or in the input data (or the parsing thereof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C89 did not allow arrays to be created with non-constant bound specifiers. C99 introduced this concept, and C11 made it an optional feature. To be 100% portable, you should use dynamic memory allocation to get around this:

```
int main() {
    int i, T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    //DYNAMIC MEMORY ALLOCATION
    int *res = malloc(T * sizeof(int)); //for T cases I'll have T outputs so saving it in an array
    if (res == NULL) { //Check for failure
        /* failure, out of memory */
        return 1;
    }
    for(i=0; i<T; i++){
        int size, j;
        scanf("%d", &size);
        //DYNAMIC MEMORY ALLOCATION
        int *ary = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        if (ary == NULL) { //Check for failure
            /* failure, out of memory */
            return 1;
        }
        for(j=0; j<size; j++){
            scanf("%d", &ary[j]);
        } //In each case I'm just declaring an array and getting a result n storing in another array
        res[i]=fn(ary, size);//Called a function got a result stored in res[]
        //FREE ALLOCATED MEMORY
        free(ary);
    }
    for(i=0; i<T; i++){
        if(res[i]==1)
            printf("YES\n");
        else
            printf("NO\n");            
    }
    //FREE ALLOCATED MEMORY
    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In 1989 C did not accept non-constant lengths. Times have changed.

Comment: C has had VLAs since C99, so unless the OP is using an ancient compiler this answer is not applicable.

Comment: @ams - updated response.